# Creating an array that can hold a non-standard type

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have a stack, I need to pop an item off the stack into an array. The things in the stack are ints, but ocaml doesn't see them that way:

```
let test = Array.make 10 0

Array.set test 0 pop
```

error:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a Stack.t -> 'a but an expression was 
expected of type int
```

I tried doing this with a symbol table too:

```
let symbol_table = amake 256 (false, 0.0)
```

but got this error

```
This expression has type int -> 'a -> 'a array
   but an expression was expected of type 'b array
```

Any tips?

Comment: Hi Jane, there is not enough detail ; particularly how pop is defined ? as well as amake.

Comment: let amake = Array.make   let pop = Stack.pop   There is also this line, which is important for the symbol table option: type command = Load of char | Store of char * int            Sorry, im not sure if you can add new lines to comments

Comment: what if you put extra ;; at the end of symbol_table line ?

Comment: could you provide the signature of amake ? (using utop for instance)

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to ocaml, I don't know what that is.

Comment: utop : a comfortable interactive environment for ocaml (really ! you'll find it with google). otherwise perform : 'ocaml < your_ocaml_file' that will provide the signatures of the various elements of your code.

Comment: Yes, I do know what utop is I didn't know what a signature is. Running that command generates this: http://pastebin.com/qr5nXCkB which is just the overall code, like I said, this is a small part. bigint.ml contains the generation of the stack itself. I appreciate the help, I feel like im so close, yet so far away.

Comment: By signature : you will get the types of your functions. In particular, you will get the type of the arguments of your functions - you will be able to verify amake which should have the same signature as Array.make.

Comment: I see, is there any reason to suspect they wouldn't be? I'm not sure that there is a different at the end of the day between the symbol_table and the test array, both result in the same error.

Comment: I agree there is no reason - but I am very surprised of the error you get in ocaml; and checking the signature of amake would just sanitize this point.

Comment: Well, what if I took a different approach. Forget the array, I just want to store the pop return as a variable and go retrieve it later. I'm currently looking into how to force pop to display as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.set test 0 pop
```

... is asking to set the 0th element of the `test` array to the value `pop`, which is a function of type `'a Stack.t -> 'a`, even though the array contains only `int` values.

You need to apply `pop` to a value of type `int Stack.t` to get an `int`.

```
Array.set test 0 (pop some_stack)
```

I don't have enough context to replicate the error with `amake`, which works fine on my side and returns a `(bool * float) array` as expected when applied to 256 and `(false, 0.0)`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have clarified. While the values within the stack are ints, the stack itself isn't initialized as an int stack. The stack generation is pretty complex, I can't ask you to go through all of it, this just seems like such a simple step to get stuck on. The array just needs to hold Stack.t items. Arg.

Answer (score 1):

Here's working code that does what you proclaim to be doing:

```
(* I have a stack. *)
let myStack = Stack.create () ;;

(* The things in the stack are ints. *)
Stack.push 42 myStack ;;
Stack.push 23 myStack ;;
Stack.push 12 myStack ;;

(* I have an array of ints. *)
let myArray = Array.make 10 0 ;;

(* I pop an element of the stack and put it into
   the 0-th place of the array. *)
Array.set myArray 0 (Stack.pop myStack) ;;

(* And I do it again with a different syntax, except
   now I place the popped element into the 1st place. *)
myArray.(1) <- Stack.pop myStack ;;
```

In comparison with your code:

1. You never made a stack, you only made an array called `test`. Perhaps you think that `Stack` is a stack, but it is not. It is a module which defines functions for working with stacks. To actually make a stack, you should use `Stack.create ()`.
2. If you write `Stack.pop` you get the **popping function**. To actually pop something you need to write `Stack.pop myStack`.

Let's practice some more: if you write `Stack.create` you get the **stack creation function**, and if you write `Stack.create ()` the function actually gets called and returns a freshly created empty stack.

Does this clarify anything?

Comment: I appreciate the reply, however, I can guarantee I do have a real stack, its generation is complex and actually occurs mostly in a different program. The problem is that Stack.pop doesn't return a standard type. It returns type: 'a Stack.t -> a' which nothing wants to play nicely with. I've decided to try to go even simpler, I just want to be able to store 1 value from pop in a variable I can refer to later.

Comment: You have a very simple error. Instead of writing `Array.set test 0 pop` you need to write `Array.set test 0 (pop s)` where `s` is your stack. (On a different note: if you do not show a stack in your question everyone will think you do not have a stack. You should provide *complete* examples!)

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `Stack.pop` and `Stack.pop myStack`?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. The problem persists however: "This expression has type Scanner.Bigint.bigint = Bigint.Bigint.bigint
       but an expression was expected of type int"                        This is rather meaningless to me, Bigint has a bunch of functions that are called from the file where the arrays are. I still think the problem is that the array or variable is looking for a specific type. Is there no "object" I can define a variable as that will take anything?

Comment: No, there is no such thing in OCaml and you do not need it. It would help if you actually explained what you're trying to do. If you are trying to put a `Bigint.Bigint.bigint` into some array, than that array should have type `Bigint.Bigint.bigint array` and not `int array`.

Comment: Look for a function which converts a `Bigint.biging.bigint` into an `int` and convert your big integer to an integer. You need to put in explicit conversions, or you need to match types. What is the reason that you have a stack of bigints but you want to put one of its elements into an array of ints?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an array of ints, the assignment is to be able to move something off the stack and then move it back on. I just need to be able to store it somehow.

Comment: You can store it as `let x = Stack.pop myStack` and OCaml will automatically compute the type of `x`, which in your case will be `Bigint.Bigint.bigint`. If you then try to use `x` as an `int` later on, it will complain. If you are going to store the popped element in an array `myArray`, you have to create an array whose elements have the same type as the elements stored on the stack. For instance, something like `Array.make 10 Bigint.Bigint.zero` (and *not* `Array.make 10 0` because `0` has the wrong type).

Comment: @JaneDoe, you accidentally fixed your array to be an array of `int` elements, by calling `Array.make 10 0`, you need to initialize it with values of type `Bigint.Bigint.bigint`, probably there should be either `Bigint.Bigint.zero` value, or function `of_int`, e.g., `(Bigint.Bigint.of_int 0)`

Comment: The type of this expression, ('_a Stack.t -> '_a) array,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized    I'm afraid bigint isn't that comprehensive as to have a builtin to_int.

Comment: @JaneDoe Is it this library: https://github.com/defrank/coursework/blob/master/cs112-Comparative_Programming_Languages/asg3-OCaml-DC/bigint.mli ? Notice that there is a good reason you cannot always convert a big integer into an integer. You have to compose `string_of_int` with `bigint_of_string`

Comment: Just don't use an array of ints. Use an array of bigints.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify *which* non-standard type you want your array to hold. But you do initialize it with a standard type, namely `int`. The line `let test = Array.make 10 0` (or equivalently `let test = [|0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0|]`) fills the array with integer zeroes. Implicitly, the type of `test` is fixed to `int array`, making it impossible to set any entry to anything other than an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to the way you have declared and used the stack. The following code is just an example.

```
let st = Stack.create();;
Stack.push 5 st;;
let pop = Stack.pop st;;
```

In your case, it looks to me you intent to use the module Stack as a stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Array.init` function to create an array from some stack.

Assuming that you have a stack any type `some_stack`, that holds elements of any type `x`, and has a function `pop` with type `some_stack -> x`, the the code will look like this:

```
let pop_from_stack number_of_elements stack = 
  Array.init number_of_elements (fun _ -> pop stack)
```